# Apply weight formula over rows of Dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a `df1` below. I make a copy of it to `df2` to conserve `df1`; then I use `df3` to compute over `df2`.

```
df2=df1.copy()
```

I want to calculate a weight such as `Weight(A) = Price(A) / Sum(row_Prices)` and return it to `df2` below the prices such as for each row I get 3 lines of data, the price, the std and the weight row. I also want to calculate the std over the row and I suppose it is of a similar form.

I have tried this

```
df3 = df2.iloc[1:,1:].div(df2.iloc[1:,1:].sum(axis=1), axis=0)
```

to get the weights and then print `df3` but it does not work.

For getting 2 rows for each date I tried stacking `.stack()` but I am probably doing it wrong. Help! Thank you

```
                       A      B      C        D     E
2006-04-27 00:00:00                                    
2006-04-28 00:00:00  69.62  69.62  6.518   65.09  69.62
2006-05-01 00:00:00   71.5   71.5  6.522   65.16   71.5
2006-05-02 00:00:00  72.34  72.34  6.669   66.55  72.34
2006-05-03 00:00:00  70.22  70.22  6.662   66.46  70.22
2006-05-04 00:00:00  68.32  68.32  6.758   67.48  68.32
2006-05-05 00:00:00     68     68  6.805   67.99     68
2006-05-08 00:00:00  67.88  67.88  6.768   67.56  67.88
```

I would like it to ouput nicely as such:

```
                            A      B      C        D     E
2006-04-27 00:00:00

2006-04-28 00:00:00                                    
            price        69.62  69.62  6.518   65.09  69.62
            weight
            std
2006-05-01 00:00:00  
            price         71.5   71.5  6.522   65.16   71.5
            weight
            std
2006-05-02 00:00:00   
            price        72.34  72.34  6.669   66.55  72.34
            weight
            std
```

Comment: yea it's just a typo here..i do get the copy of df1. thnks though

Comment: How did you get `df1`? Your index name: `2006-04-27 23:55:00` looks weird... Can you post an output of `print(df2)` and `print(df2.index)`

Comment: yea i simply modified the index to add a row at the top with another set of values, but it's not so relevant here for the question I think. I changed it the table however to avoid confusion. thanks

Comment: When posting pandas-related questions, always try to make your DataFrame easy to reconstruct. Otherwise people willing to answer your question have to waste time parsing strings, which is not very fun.

Comment: @GustavoBezerra thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no one-liner-quick-and-dirty way to achieve what you are trying to do.
You need to calculate all your data and then merge it all into a `DataFrame` that uses a multi-level index:

```
# Making weight/std DataFrames
cols = list('ABCDE')
weight = pd.DataFrame([df[col] / df.sum(axis=1) for col in df], index=cols).T
std = pd.DataFrame([df.std(axis=1) for col in df], index=cols).T

# Making MultiIndex DataFrame
mindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['price', 'weight', 'std'], df.index])
new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=mindex, columns=cols)

# Inserting data
new_df.ix['price'] = df.values
new_df.ix['weight'] = weight.values
new_df.ix['std'] = std.values

# Swapping levels
new_df = new_df.swaplevel(0, 1).sort_index()
```

The resulting `new_df` should look somewhat like this:

```
2006-04-28 price      69.62     69.62      6.518     65.09     69.62
           std      27.7829   27.7829    27.7829   27.7829   27.7829
           weight  0.248228  0.248228  0.0232397  0.232076  0.248228
2006-05-01 price       71.5      71.5      6.522     65.16      71.5
           std      28.4828   28.4828    28.4828   28.4828   28.4828
           weight  0.249841  0.249841  0.0227897  0.227687  0.249841
2006-05-02 price      72.34     72.34      6.669     66.55     72.34
           std      28.8308   28.8308    28.8308   28.8308   28.8308
           weight  0.249243  0.249243  0.0229776  0.229294  0.249243
2006-05-03 price      70.22     70.22      6.662     66.46     70.22
           std      28.0509   28.0509    28.0509   28.0509   28.0509
           weight  0.247443  0.247443  0.0234758  0.234194  0.247443
2006-05-04 price      68.32     68.32      6.758     67.48     68.32
           std      27.4399   27.4399    27.4399   27.4399   27.4399
           weight  0.244701  0.244701   0.024205  0.241692  0.244701
2006-05-05 price         68        68      6.805     67.99        68
           std      27.3661   27.3661    27.3661   27.3661   27.3661
           weight  0.243907  0.243907  0.0244086  0.243871  0.243907
2006-05-08 price      67.88     67.88      6.768     67.56     67.88
           std      27.2947   27.2947    27.2947   27.2947   27.2947
           weight  0.244201  0.244201  0.0243481   0.24305  0.244201
```

As a side note, I am not sure what kind of std you want to calculate, so I just assumed it was the row-wise price std (which will be a single/repeated value for each row).

Comment: One issue actually is that I have a type string as value in the first row indexed 2006-04-27 00:00:00 and so the weight and std function do not work as they're trying to compare string and floats.. do you know how to filter rows where only int or floats are present?

Comment: for the weight formula i get this:                                                             TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'

Comment: Make sure all your index is made of `Timestamp` types. Applying `pd.to_datetime` to the index should be enough.